# How to return value and Exception (if it is there.)

Tags: java, exception

I have helper class in which I have written this function.

```
public static String createProject(Map<String, String> params,String projectName, String projectPrefix) {
        String createdProject = null;
        try {
             createdProject=//logic for creating createdProject string which may throw two exception mentioned below
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TestLinkAPIException t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    return createdProject;
}
```

now I am calling this function from GUI part where I have written

```
String createProject=//called above function.
```

now If error occur in above code I want to show error to the user.
my question is how I get back the created **string** and error message if some **Exception** occur

Comment: What is the meaning with "Error Message"?

Comment: suppose some exception occur I want to show user that could not connect like this but if no any exception occur i want to get successfully created string value.

Comment: If there were an exception while creating the `createdProject`, how will you even have that value to be sent. It'll be `null` anyways. And if the `createdProject` is successfully created, then there won't be any exception and the value will be returned normally. I really don't see how a value will be available to be sent back in case of an exception.

Comment: yes RJ if some exception occures what I saw user as it return null value as you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a Custom Exception
2. Add your String value as an instance field of that Custom Exception.
3. Throw the custom exception with the String values passed in.

Now you have the exception and the String as well.

Comment: Dear Abimaran..the string value is successfully executed try block which return createdProject; how I get this pls help

Comment: Dear @abimaran suppose some exception occur ..I will get null value..so in that case I want to so user some message

Comment: If there are no exception, you can just pass the String values as it is. Otherwise, add the String message inside your custom exception and throw it to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Java 7, then you can use [Multi-Catch exception](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java7exceptions-486908.html) block.

```
public static String createProject(Map<String, String> params,String projectName, String projectPrefix) throws Exception {
    String createdProject = null;
    try {
        createdProject=//logic for creating createdProject string which may throw two exception mentioned below
    } catch (MalformedURLException | TestLinkAPIException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception("Error creating createdProject", e);
    }
    return createdProject;
}
```

Comment: it java 6..what I do in this case

Comment: Why you can't? To use new language features that solve your problem?

Comment: It's possible that OP is unfortunate enough to be in a situation that doesn't allow upgrades. Some businesses are still on Java 5/6...

Comment: @user3580294 How does it relate to the OP? If some businesses are on 1.4 yet the code won't compile.

Comment: Because maybe that's why OP can't upgrade?

Comment: I don't see OP is related to Java 5/6. Let OP edit the question and state it explicitly or I close it as off-top.

Comment: I never said OP's situation was related to Java 5/6. I was just giving a possible answer for why upgrading wasn't an option for OP.

Answer (score 0):

If exception occurs, createdProject is never set.

You should throw the exception from this method and catch it in block where you calling this method.

```
public static String createProject(Map<String, String> params,String projectName, String projectPrefix) throws Exception {
    String createdProject = null;
    try {
        createdProject = doSomething();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Error creating Project");
    }
    return createdProject;
}
```

and where you calling this method you will have something like this.

```
try {
    String str = createProject();
    displayTheProjectCreated(str);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Oops something went wrong
    displayErrorMessage(e);
}
```